# Map component for ExtJS

Tags: extjs, gis, extjs4.1, openstreetmap

Is there are a ExtJS component, which allows to

1. display an OpenStreetMap map in an ExtJS application,
2. display markers on certain positions on the map and
3. react to user's clicks on certain positions on the map

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a core component of Ext JS but what about  [GeoExt](http://geoext.org/index.html), which extends Ext JS? It integrates OpenLayers, which provides all the map service and user interface controls to do all the hard map work.

Comment: Looks good. What's the license? May I use it in commercial products?

Comment: Sorry, it didn't see that it's BSD.

Answer (score 2):

No.

There's only an extension for GMap: **[Ext.ux.GMapPanel](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.ux.GMapPanel)** and **[GMap Example](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/example/window/gmap.html)**

Both GMap and OSM have their own API. You can just wrap them into containers such as panels, windows, etc. If you wanna handle OSM and GMap events, use their API.